# Get currently selected Combobox value and use it as variable

Tags: delphi, combobox, tcombobox

My question is about Delphi 7.

I need to get currently selected `ComboBox1` value to use it as Floating point variable in my code:

```
t:=t+ComboBox1. // Not sure what to write here...
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not sure if the [TryStrToFloat](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.TryStrToFloat) is already in Delphi 7, but if yes I would do it this way.

```
procedure TForm1.ComboBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
var
  Value: Double;
begin
  if TryStrToFloat(ComboBox1.Text, Value) then
    T := T + Value
  else
    ShowMessage('You''ve entered wrong value ...');
end;
```

Comment: Worked and was exactly what I needed!

Comment: Hm, didn't know about `TryStrToFloat()`, although I always used `StrToFloatDef()` which is in the same unit (SysUtils). +1

Comment: @talereader, thanks. Btw. both functions, [`TryStrToFloat`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.TryStrToFloat) and [`StrToFloatDef`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.StrToFloatDef) internally calls the [`TextToFloat`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.TextToFloat) function. The only difference is how do they use it; if you write e.g. `var Output: Extended; begin if not TryStrToFloat('0.xx', Output) then Output := 0.01; end;` then you will get the same as if you call `Output := StrToFloatDef('0.xx', 0.01);` ;)

Answer (score 5):

```
// ItemIndex is the index of the selected item
// If no item is selected, the value of ItemIndex is -1
if (ComboBox1.ItemIndex >= 0) then
begin
  t := t + StrToFloat(ComboBox1.Items[ComboBox1.ItemIndex]);
end;
```

Comment: Or better [TryStrToFloat](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.TryStrToFloat) and you can use `ComboBox1.Text` instead of `ComboBox1.Items[ComboBox1.ItemIndex])`

Comment: There is one extra ")" in the code. After Removing it, it worked just fine. Thank you!

Comment: Personally I don't like this code because it uses two references to the ComboBox1.ItemIndex property. I am not sure what the read method for this property does, maybe it just reads a field so there is no performane penalty, but it just feels wrong.

Comment: @TLama: accessing ComboBox1.Text is *not* the same as ComboBox1.Items[ComboBox1.ItemIndex]). It is possible for the text to not be in the Items list.

Answer (score 2):

In Delphi 10.2 Tokyo i just do:

[string] := ComboBox.Selected.Text

Comment: This answer is not helpfull to the question that already has been answered.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays it is `ComboBox1.Text;` only :)

Comment: This could have been a comment